# Highstock date and time wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, highcharts

Newbie here.
Trying to sort my date and time in the following code.

The graph from my code works fine but its showing Thursday Jan 1 00.00.00.000 to Thursday Jan 1 00.00.00.039.
It should be showing today's date and times that are 30mins apart as that's whats coming through in the database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
// REPLACE with your Database name
$dbname = "a";
// REPLACE with Database user
$username = "";
// REPLACE with Database user password
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, reading_time FROM Sensor order by reading_time desc limit 40";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
}

$readings_time = array_column($sensor_data, 'reading_time');

// ******* Uncomment to convert readings time array to your timezone ********
$i = 0;
foreach ($readings_time as $reading){
  // Uncomment to set timezone to + 10 hours (you can change 10 to any number)
  $readings_time[$i] = date("d-F H:i", strtotime("$reading + 16 hours"));
  $i += 1;
}

$value1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value1')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value2 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value2')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value3 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value3')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value4 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value4')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value5 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value5')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$reading_time = json_encode(array_reverse($readings_time), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

/*echo $value1;
echo $value2;
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
echo $value5;
echo $reading_time;*/

$result->free();
$conn->close();
?>
```

And the code lines for the graph time are

```
xAxis: { 
  type: 'datetime',
  categories: reading_time
  },
```

Comment: Pass in an actual date, not a formatted date, and have Highstock format it for you. It's most likely getting confused because you're not passing in a recognized date format

Comment: `my code works fine but...` I love this phrase, especially because it's always followed by a description of the way in which the code is not, in fact, fine at all :-).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber I'm a newbie just learning. How would I pass in an actual date and let Highstock format it?

Comment: Hi @james Pattinson, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data. You can use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/05m98yek/ as a base.